# What is a metaphor or adjective to describe something that has gone through changes and will never be the same again?

Tags: adjectives, american-english, metaphors

I've been thinking about this for an hour and browsing for a definition, but nothing has come up.

It would be great if someone can give me something with a meaning similar to what I'm asking for.

Comment: Open "Pandoras" Box ?

Comment: You need to give more details. Give the sentence where you would use the word. See [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: "It has changed irrevocably"?

Comment: In a good way or a bad way?

Comment: The most powerful metaphor themes are extensions of the human body. This one is basically growth from childhood through adolescence to maturity (and old age). There are millions of stories that use this and millions of variations. Pick your age, count your traumas, grow up, and deal with it.

Comment: in a bad way, ex. like how pandemic changed society it'll never be the same again

Comment: Put the clarification in the question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> It is not possible to step into the same river twice.

This quote from the ancient Greek philosopher Heraclitus has been interpreted as being about the ever-changing character of humans as much as about the change of the world surrounding us, but ultimately that might just be the same thing.

From him we also obtained the probably lesser-known expression "panta rhei" (πάντα ῥεῖ), or 'everything flows'.

I think both of these will convey the meaning you seem to be looking for.